# React Native Android fails: error 3

Tags: react-native

Hope you could help me here:
I'm currently building an app which I created through CRNA and then ejected. I get the ios version right on but I'm currently struggling a lot with the android version.
When running `react-native run-android` all I can get is the following error:

```
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.myapp/com.myapp.MainActivity} does not exist.
```

I've checked `app/build.gradle`, `app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`, `app/src/main/java/com/myapp/MainActivity.java` and `app/src/main/java/com/myapp/MainActivity.java` for name errors on package. I've tried moving from `com.myapp` to `com.mebius.myapp` and `com` aswell.

Seems this comes from the only plugin I'm using. I'm keeping on the investigation

Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I had a problem with my gradle config which look like:

`include ':react-native-sensors'
project(':react-native-sensors').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir,  '../node_modules/react-native-sensors/android')
rootProject.name = 'accelapp'`

I needed to add: `include ':app'`

I don't know if it's due to the process of ejecting from CRNA or if it's due to `react-native link react-native-sensors` though.

**EDIT** After some investigation, I couldn't reproduce this issue. This leads me to say it was a faulty copy/paste...

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 possible reasons for the android app build fails to make

**1. You need to define sdk path in android/local.properties
if local.properties doesn't place then make a file names with that
add**

> sdk.dir = home/user/AndroidApp/local/Sdk

You can match with their system path..

**2. Your genymotion or avd must enable with the android studio**
**3. You must have to go with the following command**

> npm start

in new terminal .

Please go through with it.
Thanks

Comment: thanks for your answer, I actually found what was the problem by creating a dummy app with `react-native init test` and comparing files related to the process of adding plugins.

Comment: okay fine.. better to debug it creates more interest in that.